# in postgres insert query: return serial id even on onflict

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I have the following postgres table:

```
create table product_to_feedname (
    product_feedname_id serial,
    product varchar(100) not null,
    feedname varchar (300) not null,
    constraint pk_product_to_feedname PRIMARY KEY (product_feedname_id),
    constraint uc_product_to_feedname unique (product, feedname)
);
```

I am running the following insert query

```
insert into product_to_feedname
(product, feedname)
values
('product', 'feedname'),
on conflict (product, feedname) do nothing
returning product_feedname_id
```

When the product and feedname don't exist in the table, it inserts them and returns the `product_feedname_id` serial field. However, I would still like to return the id field even when there is a conflict. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the unique tuple of columns to select the `id` after the `insert`. Cascading common-table-expressions come handy for this:

```
with 
    
    -- CTE: values to insert
    params(product, feedname) as (values('product', 'feedname')),
    
    -- CTE: try to insert
    ins as (
        insert into product_to_feedname (product, feedname)
        select product feedname
        from params
        on conflict (product, feedname) do nothing
    )

-- recover the id
select pf.id 
from product_to_feedname pf
inner join params pa using (product, feedname)
```